# D.F.P Delphi Android Native Components classes.dex file merging

Tags: android, delphi, components

I have Delphi XE5 without updates.

I might have missunderstood the way I should use the BAT file.

In the build.bat template plus the install.txt, my understanding leads me to think than I should use test_classes.dex to be merged with the original classes.dex that embarcadero provides, in order to run the demos correctly.

However, I am not intereseted in testing the demos. I would like just to use the components inside my own project.

Which files should I merge?

Thanks in advance for your guidance and help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services-part-2.html.

It says:

> 1) Review the build.bat file and ensure the environment variables are set
>   correctly:
>
> 2) ANDROID needs to point to your Android SDK base directory, e.g.
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0
>   \PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk or
>   C:\Android\android-sdk-windows
>
> 3) ANDROID_PLATFORM needs to point at an installed SDK platform
>   installation, e.g. %ANDROID%\platforms\android-15 or %
>   ANDROID%\platforms\android-17. Check for one that is installed.
>
> 4) DX_LIB needs to point to the lib subdirectory under the Android SDK
>   build-tools directory, e.g. %ANDROID%\build- tools\18.0.1\lib or
>   %ANDROID%\build-tools\android-4.2.2\lib
>
> 5) EMBO_DEX needs to point to the Delphi-supplied Android classes.dex
>   file, wrapped in quotes to take care of any spaces in the path, e.g.
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD
>   Studio\12.0\lib\android\debug\classes.dex"
>
> 6) Run build.bat
>
> 7) You should now have a new file in the project directory tree called
>   java\output\dex\classes.dex
>
> This file replaces the supplied classes.dex and has the Java service
>   and broadcast receiver compiled classes included in it.
>
> 8) Set the new classes.dex for deployment